# Attribute based sitemap node not selecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

Consider this setup:

```
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Super Title", Key = "Super", ParentKey = "topNav")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Sub Title", ParentKey = "Super")]
    public ActionResult SubAction(Guid id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When navigating to the SubAction the **Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap.CurrentNode is always null.**
*Except sometimes it works for a single Guid only (I suppose the first one requested)*

Why?

Apart from this instance it works for all other actions in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add PreservedRouteParameters="true"

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Sub Title", ParentKey = "Super", PreservedRouteParameters = "id")]
public ActionResult SubAction(Guid id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This covers the "how", for the "why" see this post: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position